# Expected number of rejected null hypotheses using FDR

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, hypothesis-testing

**Problem:**

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{500}$ be independently identically distributed. For a constant $a$, suppose we know the probability $$P(X_i\leq k*a)\ \forall k = 1,\dots , 500.$$

We now sort the $X$'s so that $X_{(1)}\leq X_{(2)}\leq \dots\leq X_{(500)}$.

Find the expectation $E(K)$, $K = \max(k)$ where $k$ satisfies $X_{(k)}\leq k*a.$

**My attempt:**

I don't really have any rigorous proof, but I simply think of this as an "average" problem, and so the answer would be $$E(K) = \sum_{k=1}^{500}P(X_i\leq k*a).$$

**Note:**
You may notice that this problem relates to false discovery rate. I have been banging my head against the wall for couple days and can't seem to get anywhere. Any help/suggestions/ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: There is a gap in your question. $K$ may not be defined. If $X_{(k)} > k*a$ for all $k$ then there is no maximum. I presume in this case you would wish to set $K$ to zero?

Comment: @ScottBurns Yes, that's what I meant. $K = 0$ if there is no $k$ satisfies that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write 
$$
\mathbb{E}[K] = \sum_{k\ge 1} \mathbb{P}(K\ge k) = \sum_{k= 1}^n \mathbb{P}(\text{at least $k$ variables do not exceed $ka$})
$$
Note that the number of variables not exceeding $ka$ has a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p_{k} = \mathbb{P}(X_1\le ka)$. Therefore, 
$$
\mathbb{E}[K]= \sum_{k= 1}^n \sum_{j=k}^n {n\choose j}p_k^j (1-p_k)^{n-j}.
$$
It is unlikely that there is a simpler expression for $\mathbb{E}[K]$. For some particular distributions it might be possible to derive asymptotics. Say, if $\mathbb{P}(|X_1|>x) = o(x^{-1}\log^{-1} x)$, $x\to\infty$, then $K=n$ with overwhelming probability, so $\mathbb{E}[K] \sim n$, $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I'll have to sit down and think about your solution more, but here's the bounty I promised. Thank you for taking your time thinking about this problem!

Comment: Is the top line correct? e.g. $n=3$, $k=2$, $a=\frac{1}{4}$. Take the $X$ variables to be 0.6, 0.7, 0.74. Then $K=3$ so $K\geq 2$ but no variables are less than $ka=0.5$.

Comment: @S.Catterall, you're right. I'll think more.

Comment: @zhoraster I guess you can compute $\mathbb{P}(K\ge k)$ by integrating the joint density (assuming it exists) of the order statistics over a certain region of 500 dimensional space. This might give an answer that is (a) no longer just a function of the quantities $P(X_i\leq k*a)$, and (b) is even less simple than the expresion you have derived.